# /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, macos, bash

found some answers here that didn't help me so much

```
ohad@Macintosh-2:/Volumes/develpment/global_constants (master *+)$ node_modules/.bin/mocha -w
bash: node_modules/.bin/mocha: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

the file is

```
cat node_modules/.bin/mocha
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * This tiny wrapper file checks for known node flags and appends them
```

This happens not just here but every time I try to run a bash from my comp. 
I'm new to bash and not so familiar with linux, can somebody help?

Edit:
I'm using Osx.
I've tried

```
find ~ -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} 2> /dev/null \;
```

it's still running..

tried editing and removing all stuff from my .bash_profile

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"'
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Textmate's ruby
export TM_RUBY=rvm-auto-ruby

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin/:/usr/local/mysql-5.1.58-osx10.6-x86_64/bin:$PATH"
#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export GEM_EDITOR='mate'
export VBOX_IP="127.0.0.1"
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin

    bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'

    # Get the aliases and functions
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
    fi
    source ~/.git-completion.bash

    # User specific environment and startup programs
    function crc32 { cksum -o3 "$@"|ruby -e 'STDIN.each{|a|a=a.split;printf "%08X\t%s\n",a[0],a[2..-1].join(" ")}'; }

    #required to get X11 working right (for ssh -X and gtk)
    export DISPLAY=:0

    #git
    source ~/.git-completion.bash
    GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true

    #modified (colourised) prompt
    #export PS1='\h:\w \e[31m\u\e[0m$'
    #export PS1='[\t] \h:\w \u\$ '

    #export PS1='\u@\h:\w \$ '

    #git-bash
#   export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    export PS1='\[\033[32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[34m\]\w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ '


    # ls aliases

# colors that "ls" uses.
    export CLICOLOR=1
    #export LS_COLORS="no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:"

    #export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;43;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32;41:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:'

    LS_COLORS=''
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'no=0'           # Normal text
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'fi=0'           # Regular file
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=36'          # Directory
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ln=01;36'       # Symbolic link
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'pi=33'          # Named pipe
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'so=01;35'       # Socket
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'do=01;35'       # DO
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'bd=01;37'       # Block device
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'cd=01;37'       # Character device
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ex=35'          # Executable file
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*FAQ=31;7'      # FAQs
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*README=31;7'   # READMEs
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*INSTALL=31;7'  # INSTALLs
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.sh=47;31'     # Shell-Scripts
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.vim=35'       # Vim-"Scripts"
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.swp=00;44;37' # Swapfiles (Vim)
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.sl=30;33'     # Slang-Scripts
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*,v=5;34;93'    # Versioncontrols
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'or=01;05;31'    # Orphaned link
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.c=33'         # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.C=33'         # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.h=33'         # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.cc=33'        # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.py=33'        # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.rb=33'        # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.awk=33'       # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.pl=33'        # Sources
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.jpg=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.jpeg=0;32'    # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.JPG=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.gif=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.png=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.jpeg=0;32'    # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.ppm=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.pgm=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.pbm=0;32'     # Images
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.tar=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.tgz=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.gz=31'        # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.zip=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.sit=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.lha=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.lzh=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.rar=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.arj=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.bz2=31'       # Archive
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.avi=35'       # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.mpg=35'       # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.mpeg=35'      # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.divx=35'      # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.xvid=35'      # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.mov=35'       # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.mp4=35'       # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.m4v=35'       # Video
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.wmv=35'       # VIdeo
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.mp3=37'       # Audio
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.ogg=37'       # Audio
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.wav=37'       # Audio
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.au=37'        # Audio
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.html=36'      # HTML
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.htm=1;34'     # HTML
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.php=1;45'     # PHP
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.doc=1;34'     # MS-Word
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.txt=1;34'     # Plain/Text
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.o=1;36'       # Object-Files
    LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'*.a=1;36'       # Shared-libs
    export LS_COLORS

export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
clean(){ #various commands to clean files that are weirdly changed.
  echo "running git checkout Gemfile.lock "
    git checkout Gemfile.lock
      echo "running rm dump.rdb "
        rm dump.rdb
      echo "Done cleaning"
  }

  cl(){
        clean
    }

    startup(){ #start up commands
      echo "redis"
        sudo redis-server
       echo "mongo"
         sudo mongod
      echo "rabbit"
         rabbitmq-server
    }

    st(){
        startup
    }
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi

if [ -f ~/bash_completion.d/knife ]; then
  . ~/bash_completion.d/knife
fi

[ -s "/Users/ohad/.nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/Users/ohad/.nvm/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Comment: Does `/bin/csh` exist? Does it have the right permissions?

Comment: Please clarify if you only mean Linux or OSX. Also, what answers did you find that didn't help you? Why didn't they help you?

Comment: Firstly, what is the result of `which node`. Second, does it work when you invoke `node` directly?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the result is `which node
/usr/local/bin/node`. for your second question - yes it works. what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

I think you were on the right track with your `xattr` command. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952612/mac-os-usr-bin-env-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted) provides an explanation:

> Did you happen to open/save the file in TextEdit?
>
> That can introduce filesystem metadata (quarantine attribute)
>   [leading to the symptom you describe](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.sys.mac.system/OMuXCAXFWOE).

The command you ran:

`find ~ -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} 2> /dev/null \;`

Will only remove the quarantine attribute on files beneath your home directory (`~`). You should try:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Volumes/develpment/global_constants/node_modules/.bin/mocha`

And/or replace `~` in your original command with one of the parent directories of the script(s) you're having trouble running.

Comment: I'm trying but it takes forever..

Comment: I think there's a `-r` recursive option that you could combine with the `-d`, i.e. `-dr`. It might be quicker than using find/exec.

Answer (score 1):

"Operation not permitted"

Sometimes "Opreation not permitted" means too that you're trying to open an executable file which isn't.

You can use `sudo chmod +x yourfile`

Did you tried as user **root** ? `sudo yourcommand`

For some reasons, when I use sudo, it doesn't always works.

So you can try `sudo su`.

If you're not in the sudoers file, just add you with `su` then `visudo`.

Comment: still doesn't work.. getting the same error

Comment: i've edited my question to add tried outs